# How to apply DRY principle in javascript code snippet

Tags: javascript, dry

I have this code snippet and it is obviously that it could be avoided repeating of those two regular expression in if condition because as you can see they differs only in one digit.

```
'phoneNumberRegexp': function (phoneCode, homeNumber) {
    if (phoneCode === 372) {
        return /[\s]*^\s*(\d[\s\-\u00b7]*){6,13}$/.test(homeNumber);
    } else {
        return /[\s]*^\s*(\d[\s\-\u00b7]*){8,13}$/.test(homeNumber);
    }
}
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you really want you can create a dynamic regex and use it

```
'phoneNumberRegexp': function (phoneCode, homeNumber) {
    return new RegExp('[\\s]*^\\s*(\\d[\\s\\-\\u00b7]*){' + (phoneCode === 372 ? 6 : 8) + ',13}$').test(homeNumber);
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought but the amount of escaping makes this more unreadable. IMO.

Comment: @Arun Thanks, it is solution!

Comment: @bane975 You don't actually need to escape the regex fragments if you use `.source` on individual regex fragments. Please see what I mean below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using RegExp object.

```
'phoneNumberRegexp': function (phoneCode, homeNumber) {
    var n = 8
    if (phoneCode === 372) n = 6;
    var pattern = "[\\s]*^\\s*(\\d[\\s\\-\\u00b7]*){"+n+",13}$";
    var re = new RegExp(pattern);
    return re.test(homeNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the individual regex's. Just use the `.source` method of each part to join individual regex fragments together. It's much easier to read and maintain.

```
'phoneNumberRegexp': (phoneCode, homeNumber) {
    return new RegExp(/[\s]*^\s*(\d[\s\-\u00b7]*){/.source + (phoneCode===372?6:8) + /,13}$/.source).test(homeNumber);
}
```